# Python RPy2 function with multiple input arguments

Tags: python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv, rpy2

I am looking to call an `rPy2` function with multiple input parameters. Here is the R function [write.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) that I am trying to use. It has multiple input parameters and I need to specify more than one such parameter.

If I use it without the optional parameter `row.names` and `column.names`, it works like this:

```
r("write.csv")(d,file='myfilename.csv')
```

For my requirements, I must issue this command with the optional parameters `row.names` and `column.names`. So, I tried:

```
r('write.csv')(d, file='myfilename.csv', row.names=FALSE, column.names=FALSE)
```

but I got this error message:

```
  File "/home/UserName/test.py", line 12
    r("write.csv")(d,file='myfilename.csv',row.names=FALSE, column.names=FALSE)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/UserName/test.py"]
[dir: /home/UserName]
[path: /home/UserName/bin:/home/UserName/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
.../usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

How can I achieve `write.csv` with `row.names=FALSE` and `column.names=FALSE`, in `rPy2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's `**`.

See the note here: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_functions.html#callable

Comment: I tried but am getting an error - here is the code: `from rpy2.robjects.functions import SignatureTranslatedFunction;            STM = SignatureTranslatedFunction;            write.par = STM(write.par(**{'x':dataf,'file':'testing.csv','row.names':False}))`. This gives the error: `AttributeError: 'SignatureTranslatedFunction' object has no attribute 'par'`. Could you provide one example of your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ony of my mistakes was that I should have replaced `.` by `_`, as shown in the docs [here](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_functions.html?highlight=function#callable):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
base.rank(0, na_last = True)
```

so I would analogously need `row_names = TRUE`. However, the `.` in `write.csv()` still remained, so this only solved part of the question. Ok, so I tried a few things to get an answer:

Generating sample data:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, globalenv
from rpy2.robjects import IntVector, DataFrame

d = {'a': IntVector((1,2,3)), 'b': IntVector((4,5,6))}
dataf = DataFrame(d)
```

Attempts follow - 1. did not work, 2. and 3. did work:

1:

```
r('write_csv')(x=dataf,file='testing.csv',row_names=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\FileD\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    r('write_csv')(x=dataf,file='testing.csv',row_names=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 321, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'write_csv'
..not found    
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'write_csv' not found
```

2.

```
r('''
write_csv <- function(x,verbose=FALSE)
write.csv(x,file='testing.csv',row.names=FALSE)
''')
r['write_csv'](dataf)
```

3.

```
globalenv['dataf'] = dataf
r("write.csv(dataf,file='testing2.csv',row.names=FALSE)")
```

I was really hoping attempt 1. would have worked. It seemed I had reproduced the example in the docs `base.rank(0, na_last = True)`, but I think something might have still been missing.